# Predict OR Classify set of values by using independent variables using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset like this:

```
y1 | y2 | y3 | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | ..... xn|
1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 1  | ..... 1 |
1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | ..... 0 |
1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 1  | ..... 0 |
```

Using the above data, I have independent variables x1, x2 ... xn and dependent variables y1, y2, y3. I want to run some (Machine learning) algorithm which can classify not only one dependent variable but a set of dependent variables. One way is to learn the model one by one for each dependent variable but this could be too time consuming because originally I have more than 50 dependent variables. Is there any suggestions about the algorithm which can do it for me in a faster way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification):

> Multioutput classification support can be added to any classifier with
>   MultiOutputClassifier. This strategy consists of fitting one
>   classifier per target. This allows multiple target variable
>   classifications. The purpose of this class is to extend estimators to
>   be able to estimate a series of target functions (f1,f2,f3...,fn) that
>   are trained on a single X predictor matrix to predict a series of
>   reponses (y1,y2,y3...,yn).

So you can use this fantistic library to do the work for you :)